# Local Notification dissapperas from the status bar of the phone.How can I make it stay there untill someone acces it

Tags: iphone, notifications

I have the following code which creates a local Notification that appears in the status bar of the phone.The notification created dissappears after a short while even if I don't acces it.

```
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] autorelease];

if (!localNotification) 
    return;

// Current date
NSDate *date = [NSDate date]; 

// Add one minute to the current time
NSDate *dateToFire = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:60];

// Set the fire date/time
[localNotification setFireDate:dateToFire];
[localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
localNotification.repeatInterval = 0;

// Create a payload to go along with the notification
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Value 1", @"Value 2", nil];
NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:array forKey:@"payload"];
[localNotification setUserInfo:data];


// Setup alert notification
[localNotification setAlertBody:@"Incoming notification"];
[localNotification setAlertAction:@"Open App"];
[localNotification setHasAction:YES];    

// Schedule the notification        
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

Can someone help me create a notification that stays in the status bar until the user accesses it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do this, the iOS SDK does not provide any way of making the notification stay in the statusbar until the user dismiss it.